# Factor: int to factor

Tags: r

I want to convert int to factor and with the appropriate season name. The code below accomplished that, but when I went to check my data with `glimpse()` my df still shows it as an int. Is it because I am using `as.factor()` instead of `factor()`?

```
day %>%
  as.tibble()%>%
  mutate(season = as.factor(season)%>%
           fct_recode("Spring" = "1", "Summer" = "2", "Fall" = "3", "Winter" = "4"))

glimpse(day)
```

Comment: Did you save day like this `newday<-day and your manipulations`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to save your manipulations. That is:

```
newday<-day %>%
  as.tibble()%>%
  mutate(season = as.factor(season)%>%
           fct_recode("Spring" = "1", "Summer" = "2", "Fall" = "3", "Winter" = "4"))
```

Then check `str(newday)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `%<>%` (compound assignment operator) to make the changes in place

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
day %<>%
   as.tibble %<>%
   mutate(season = as.factor(season)%<>%
           fct_recode("Spring" = "1", "Summer" = "2", "Fall" = "3", "Winter" = "4"))
```